How to interpret GAMs with multiple vs single variables?
So, I have been trying to use GAMs to observe the relationship between total economic damages (due to a certain event) and a variety of factors, including, total number of events, total number of people affected, level of infrastructure development etc.
Here's what I have tried so far:
library(mgcv)

model1 <-gam(total_damages ~ s(total_events) + s(total_affected) + 
    s(coastlines) + s(total_gdp, k=1) + s(urban_landarea) + 
    s(infrastructure_index), tw(link="log"))

I used tw(link="log") because total_damages are not normally distributed. I plotted a histogram to check. I also noticed that the variance of this variable is much bigger than its mean. However, if using tweedie is wrong here, please let me know.
Also, I'm not too sure if I should be using a smooth function for all the independent variables. I noticed that total_gdp has a linear relationship with total_damages, so I set k=1. However, I'm not too sure if there are any repercussions to using smooth functions for so many variables.
I want to show you the results I got from this model.
summary(model1)


I don't think that the p-values are of much use in this case. I wonder if the adjusted $R^2$ and "deviance explained" values are of worth here. Please let me know if they mean something important in the case of GAMs.
I want to show one of the charts here:
plot(model1)


The image shows the plot between an independent variable (infrastructure_index) and the smooth s(infrastructure_index). The line looks kinda straight but looking at the coefficients (coef(model1)) tells me that they frequently fluctuate between negative and positive values. I think it means that there's an irregular relationship between infrastructure_index and total_damages?
I tried modelling another GAM, but this time, I just focused on using 1 independent variable, "infrastructure_index".
model2 <- gam(total_damages ~ s(infrastructure_index))

here's the model summary:

The adjusted $R^2$ and deviance explained values have fallen. But the plot has become much clearer and I feel like I have a more clear understanding of the relationship between infrastructure_index and total_damages:


Is the GAM model with multiple variables a better tool for understanding the relationship between the independent variables and total_damages?

Are GAMs with single variables less useful? Why do the two graphs differ so much?

When should I use GAMs with multiple vs single variables?



In addition to the useful answer from Ben, I wanted to directly answer your last questions:

Is the GAM model with multiple variables a better tool for understanding the relationship between the independent variables and total_damages?

Admittedly, the post could use some more context about what the variables actually mean and how they relate to the theoretical model you are testing (that is what I assume your purpose is here at least). Because of this, I would only say that if the model with more variables is theoretically defensible and isn't poorly fit (see Ben's points about overfitting for example), then the multiple variable case is probably preferred. .

Are GAMs with single variables less useful?

GAMs with single variables can be useful for explaining simple phenomena or simple models. The classic example usually demonstrated in GAMs is that of the Silverman acceleration data, where it is clear that a large driver of head acceleration in motorcycle crashes is the time of the crash:

However, there may be other alternative, more complex models which may be more useful (types of motorcycles may interact with this relationship for example).

Why do the two graphs differ so much?

There could be a handful of reasons for this. Probably the most likely cause is that one of your variables is suppressing the relationship of the other, which has downgraded the magnitude of the association. As Ben also noted, it could also be an overfit model, and so much of the explained variance may be scooped up by having too many predictors absorbing the this variance.

When should I use GAMs with multiple vs single variables?

That will depend entirely on your purpose, which I have outlined already to some degree in the beginning of this answer. One final point I wanted to address in your post:

Also, I'm not too sure if I should be using a smooth function for all the independent variables.

Theoretically, there is nothing stopping you from fitting every effect as a spline. But if the effect is clearly linear, it may be helpful to leave them without splines. A good reason to do this would be that it potentially helps with interpretation of the effects (e.g. we now have a consistent association in the form of a slope versus a conditional association which doesn't have a directly interpretable effect).


a Tweedie distribution is useful when the data are continuous and non-negative (mostly positive, but with some values that are exactly zero as well)
your data set appears to have 166 complete observations (n=166 in the summary). That suggests according to standard rules of thumb (e.g. see Harrell Regression Modeling Strategies chapter 4) that you might be slightly overfitting your data (the sum of the effective number of parameters [ecdf in the summary table] is about 16, which gives (# obs)/(# params) of about 10; this means your model is at the upper limit of what you should be squeezing into the model (it's better to aim for n/p around 15). On the other hand, GAMs automatically reduce the complexity of the model where they can; you can see that urban_landarea has been reduced to an ecdf of 1, which means it has been simplified as much as possible. You might try specifying select = TRUE, which allows gam() to remove variables from the model completely if warranted (rather than reducing them to linear effects).
the adjusted R^2 has approximately the same meaning it does in linear models: it is approximately the expected proportion of variance in a new sample that will be explained by the model ("approximately" because R^2 is tricky for non-Gaussian models; "in a new sample" because it's an adjusted R^2 value)
it's generally not worth fussing with univariate models (as in your model 2)
I don't know why your plot of the infrastructure_index smooth is plotted on a scale (approx. -100 to +75) where it shows barely any variation; we might need a reproducible example to understand that (I don't quite understand your statement


The line looks kinda straight but looking at the coefficients (coef(model1)) tells me that they frequently fluctuate between negative and positive values

: how do the coefficients tell you that? (The coefficients of a spline term are not easily interpretable as the pattern of magnitude of the variable — alternating positive and negative coefficients doesn't imply that the pattern is fluctuating ...)

> I don't know why your plot of the infrastructure_index smooth is plotted on a scale (approx. -100 to +75) where it shows barely any variation ---
I suspect that the credible intervals on one of the other smooths in the model have exploded for some part of its covariate range, perhaps due to concurvity among the other terms.
